# Generators of of $p$-adic congruence subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $p$ be an odd prime, $i$ a fixed positive integer and let $\Gamma_i$ denote the kernel of the map $\SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\rightarrow \SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p/p^i\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then the minimal cardinality of a topological generating set for $\Gamma_i$ is $3$.

**Question:** Is there a topological generating set $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ of $\Gamma_i$ such that $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ are all unipotent matrices?

Comment: I believe the answer should be "yes".  Here is a sketch:  for $i \geq 1$, the groups $\Gamma_i$ are uniform pro-$p$- groups, and therefore $H^1(\Gamma_i,\mathbb{F}_p) = ((\Gamma_i)_\Phi)^*$ is 3-dim'l, where $(-)_\Phi$ denotes the Frattini quotient and $*$ is the $\mathbb{F}_p$ dual.  The quotient $(\Gamma_i)_\Phi$ will be isomorphic to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, so if the $\gamma_i$ are topological generators of $\Gamma_i$, then their images in $(\Gamma_i)_\Phi$ should be (ab. group) generators of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ ... (cont'd)

Comment: Thus, it suffices to find nilpotent matrices which generate $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ as an abelian group, and translate them back to $\Gamma_i$.  This isn't so bad to do: if my calculations are correct, the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & p^i \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ p^i & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 + p^i & -p^i \\ p^i & 1 - p^i\end{pmatrix}$ should do the trick.

Comment: @krl I think you are right, thanks!